# ajax dropdown menu with days of this week to update dropdown of time of the booking times from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a booking table with time and date as below

Booked table:

```
ID TIME   Date
1  2:30   Wednesday
2  11:30  Thursday
3  10:30  Friday
```

Available hours table

Available table:

```
ID TIME   
1  8:30   
2  9:30  
3  10:30  
4  11:30  
5  12:30  
6  1:30  
7  2:30
```

Now i need a drop down with 7 days starting from today to next week example:

```
<select><option value="today">today</option><option>tomorrow</option><option>sunday</option><option>moday</option><option>tuesday</option><option>wednesday</option><option>thursday</option></select>
```

which will update another available times dropdown:
so lets say we select today friday: then the dropdown should change to:

```
<select><option value="">8:30</option><option>9:30</option><option>11:30</option><option>12:30</option><option>1:30</option><option>2:30</option></select>
```

Any idea how to do this with ajax

Comment: what happens when someone books a slot? Should that slot remain available for others to book?

Comment: no it should be removed from the time menu , as in the example if you select friday , then 10:30 isn't shown

Comment: handle the "change" event of the first dropdown, make an ajax request to the server for the times relating to the option chosen (you might want to give your option tags value attributes, so you can easily get the selected day's ID, it might need to be an actual date like "2017-10-21", rather than "tomorrow", so the server is 100% clear what you mean). Get the ajax response, clear out your times dropdown and insert new option tags with the times in. Lots of examples of ajax-dependent dropdowns online if you google it. But that's the basic idea.